# Setting Framebuffer splash resolution when exiting X

Tags: linux, console, framebuffer, backtrack, resolution

I installed a copy of BackTrack 5 R2 (Ubuntu 10.04) to my HDD and dual-booted with Windows 7. After a bit of tweaking I set about updating the native Intel drivers because it was only allowing me to choose between 800x600 and 1024x768 resolutions and I have a widescreen laptop.

Uninstalled current drivers, added the new repository, and updated the latest Intel drivers. Start X and voila! 1366x768 resolution. Perfect...almost.

BT uses a custom [framebuffer bootsplash](https://www.backtrack-linux.com/backtrack-graphics-customization/) that is hard-coded to 1024x768 resolution. When I start X server (KDE) my resolution changes as it should. However, when I end my session, the resolution does not change back and I'm stuck staring at a bland framebuffer because the theme won't work at the wider resolution.

Now I realize this isn't the end of the world, but I'm wondering if there is a way to configure this so that it will return to the 1024x768 resolution when I end my X session.

I've tried resetting the resolution with `fbset` but it only shrinks the usable portion of the screen. It does not stretch the output to fill the display.

Comment: Have you tried to boot with `modeset` parameter ?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It works as it should when I boot.  It's only after starting X that I have a problem.  It won't return to the resolution it booted with.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? any new developments? Or, did you solve it back then?

Comment: @AlexStragies Unfortunately, I was never able to find a solution to this issue.